# Other time formats in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts

Is it possible to use other timestamp formats like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, instead of milliseconds as data values?

**Usually**:

```
data:[1318333500000, 1318403640000]
```

**What I want**:

```
data:['2011-10-11 13:45:00', '2011-10-12 09:14:00']
```

First I thought I can use the data Module (data.js) of Highcharts, but the [parseDate](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.parseDate) callback won't work if I add my data through the `series.data` option.

Comment: Is the problem that you have `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` as input, or that you want `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` as output, because both of those are doable? Regardless, highchart officially only supports milliseconds. Sometimes other formats work in some ways, but they fail unpredictably.

Comment: I want `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` as input format, or a working callback to transform it to milliseconds

Comment: I would format the data before inserting into highcharts. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fj2yy8qw/18/

Comment: That solution is ok, thought it's cleaner to use Highcharts own functions.

Comment: I agree that using Highcharts own functions is cleaner. But I have not found a good way to solve this particular problem in that way.